# Content Search Web part not visible in SP 2013 Online

Tags: 2013, content-search-web-part

I am trying to configure a Content Search web part for a team site on SP13 online. There is nothing wrong with the query ("test query" works fine) but when i save the web part it is not showing any results.

Comment: Can you attach your query to the post?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem... have you solved it yet?

Comment: Did you find the solution? I'm having the same issue

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you add your SP online site to your trusted sites. If the query works in the Test is something with the client side code, and trusted sites could fix it. If not, try to use the "debug" display template and see if show something.